# Can someone provide me an example on how to convert this data format to JSON?

Tags: json

How do i convert json text file to..

```
var nested_obj = { pic: "jaedongImage", name: "ananth", team: "evil geniuses", server: "NA" };
```

My text file as below..

```
{

 "data": [

{

"pic": "jaedongImage,"

"name": "ananth",

"team": "evil geniuses",

"server": "N/A"

}

]

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what you're asking, but: The JSON depicts an object with one property, `data`, which refers to an array. The array has one entry, which is the object you wanted. From your initial code sample, it looks like you're using JavaScript, so: Assuming you're receiving **text** (a string) in JSON format, you would parse it using `JSON.parse`, and then get at that object via `data[0]`:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
var pic = obj.data[0];
```